# grep: ./Coding/CNL.md: Is a directory

Tags: bash

I intend to find all the markdown files which contain the word `desire` using pipeline

```
In [37]: !find -E . -iregex ".*/[^/]+\.md" -print0 -exec grep -i "desire" "{}" \; | grep ".md"
grep: ./Coding/CNL.md: Is a directory
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: `find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec grep -l -i desire '{}' +`

Comment: `!find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec grep -i desire '{}' + | grep -o ".*\.md"` it works, what's the problem with my script, I think `./Coding/CNL.md: ` is text in find's output.@melpomene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the errors:

```
grep: ./Coding/CNL.md: Is a directory
```

means a directory was passed as argument to `grep` and grep can't process directories, adding `-type f` option, filters only files.

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

Means stadard input (because grep is used in a pipe there's no file name) is detected as a binary file, grep doesn't print ouput to avoid special characters or escape sequences to be send to terminal. This may be due to `-print0` option which uses `NUL` character (or `\0`) as output delimiter.

It's not clear why are you using `-print0` and `-exec grep ...`, this will mix file names and files' content.

Comment: I am afraid that filenames found cannot be read correctly by `grep pattern *files`

Comment: maybe you mixed 2 different syntax : `find .. -exec grep .. {} \;` and `find .. -print0 | xargs -0 grep ..`

Comment: from your intention @melpomene comment is the right syntax